# Why are equations not visible in the Review pane?

Tags: bug

I have observed that In the Moderator's tool, review pane, equations are not quite visible.

Why is this so? Is this a bug?

Comment: mathjax is probably not supported on that page... I agree, it would be useful to have it there too.